# Is "Egyptian Year" the same as a modern sidereal year?

Tags: astronomy, terminology, history

Copernicus uses the term "Egyptian Year" throughout his discussions of the movements of the Earth, and of his and other models of the movements of the planets; but is unclear from his text, or from the [general definitions](http://www.egypt-tehuti.org/articles/egyptian-calendar.html) I've found, what this corresponds to in modern astronomical terms.

What, precisely, is an "Egyptian Year"? Is it identical with a modern sidereal year; if not, what are the correct conversions between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Egyptian year is not the same as sidereal year. [Egyptian year](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LVp_gkwyvC8C&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=%22egyptian%20year%22%20copernicus&source=bl&ots=NPpYLGuKHV&sig=kJoC8HNe9A1cg5RVWFYiAR3tN6o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=K4RrULLDKsnE2gXqkoDQAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22egyptian%20year%22%20copernicus&f=false) is exactly 365 days, whereas [sidereal year](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/astronomy/SiderealYear.html) is approximately 365.256 days.